# Links not being created between containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a very simple 2 container application, 1 running Tomcat the other Redis. I am attempting to use docker-compose but the link between the containers is not working.

If I simply do a run with the below commands all is happy.

```
docker run -d --name db redis
docker run -d -P --name web --link db web
```

When I attempt to use the below docker-compose.yml file there is no link between the containers.

```
version: '2'
 services:
  web:
   image: web
  links:
   - redis
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
 redis:
  image: redis
```

There are no environment variables created using docker-compose and the /etc/hosts file is not updating.

I'm puzzled since this is literally a copy of several of the examples I've found on numerous site, including docker.com. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 2 of compose you don't need links. You should be able to connect to the redis container just be referring to the hostname `redis`. It doesn't appear in environment variables or /etc/hosts as networking is now a first-class feature in docker, and instead it uses built-in DNS resolution.

Since the new networking model came in, each container is started on a network (`default` by er, default) and can communicate with each other by using their service or container name.

Comment: Ah, thanks very much. Just testing things out and it works like a charm.